# How to reference columns in External list in Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-bcs

I have two external lists: (Parents, Students). I need to display Parents `Name` in Students List as a Dropdown field.

And if I save the student form,  ParentID should be stored in DB.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To accomplish this you will need to create a custom form with a dropdown box and use the SharePoint javascript API to pull parents name in the dropdown field. You could also make a lookup column to the parent list in the student list and get the same functionality.

edited to give example

```
var siteUrl = '/sites/MySiteCollection';

 function retrieveListItems() {

var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Announcements');

var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><Query><Where><Geq><FieldRef Name=\'ID\'/>' + 
    '<Value Type=\'Number\'>1</Value></Geq></Where></Query><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>');
this.collListItem = oList.getItems(camlQuery);

clientContext.load(collListItem);

clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded),      Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));        

}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {

var listItemInfo = '';

var listItemEnumerator = collListItem.getEnumerator();

while (listItemEnumerator.moveNext()) {
    var oListItem = listItemEnumerator.get_current();
    listItemInfo += '\nID: ' + oListItem.get_id() + 
        '\nTitle: ' + oListItem.get_item('Title') + 
        '\nBody: ' + oListItem.get_item('Body');
}

alert(listItemInfo.toString());
 }

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur interest. I am very new for sharepoint. Please give me any link regarding this buddy ... Well I am using BCs not normal sharepoint list.

Comment: here you go the Javascript oject model for sharepoint http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh185015(v=office.14).aspx